# How do I proxy a docker container with nginx running on the host?

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

Edit: The purpose of this was to only allow UDP connections to a specific port of it used a specific sub domain. I’ve now learned udp doesn’t have a concept of subdomains, making this entire question pointless.

I have nginx running on the host, and a program I want to proxy running in a docker container. How do I configure nginx to redirect traffic from a specific subdomain to that container? I can't find any examples for that setup, only both on the host or both in docker containers. I've used proxy_pass before, but only for both on the host. Also, I'd prefer not to publish the IP from the docker container to the host; I'd rather let nginx do the forwarding.

Comment: There's nothing unique to Docker in this configuration: just treat the container like any other nginx backend and point nginx at the container's ip address. You would probably be better off running nginx in a container (because then you could use docker's name resolution to refer to the container rather than the ip address, which ends up being much more flexible).

Comment: Do docker containers keep their IP address if they restart? I know how to get the IP from the command line, but not dynamically from within the nginx config. I'm using nginx on the host because I already had it set up for another project, and I'd rather reusing my existing configuration if possible. Setting up an nginx container is the last option I want to take.

Comment: I think that any solution that relies on the container ip address is faulty. Even if a container keeps its ip address on *restart*, you are going to be creating *new* containers when you have configuration or package updates.

Comment: You should treat your containerized process the same way you treat the nginx or any other process on the host.  Use `docker run -p` to get a port for it visible from the host, and then `proxy_pass` to that.

Comment: I was trying to use nginx to make a single udp port only usable for a specific subdomain. It turns out UDP has no concept of subdomains, making all of this pointless. I'll just use `docker run -p PORT:PORT` like I was before and call it a day. Thanks for commenting on my question.

Answer (score 2):

This config should work:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  subdomain.domain.tld;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<IP of Docker Container>:<port>;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the IP address of the docker container at runtime? Also, the traffic is UDP, so I can't use the http prefix.

Comment: You can't get the IP address of the container without having root-level privileges, and it can in fact change during very routine container maintenance operations.

Answer (score 2):

In response to @IHuman I would have the docker container port-forward to ports on the host. With that, the nginx running on the host will have all locations refer to the loopback ip

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  subdomain.domain.tld;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port1>;
    }
}
```